Carbery–Wright style inequality for log-sum-exp
I am searching for an analog of the following well-known anti concentration inequality for polynomials (stated in simplified form).
Theorem (Carbery–Wright): Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a degree-$d$ polynomial and $\mu$ a log-concave probability measure. Then, for any $q > 0$,
$$\mu\{x: |f(x)| < \delta\} \le Cq\delta^{1/d}\bigg/\left(\int |f|^{\frac q d}\,d\mu\right)^{\frac 1 q}.$$
I am interested in an analogous result where the polynomial $f$ is replaced by a function of the form
$$f_{\beta,t}(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}\log\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\beta x_i}\right\} - t.$$
The goal would be to work out an a result analogous to the one above, where the right hand side has explicit dependence on $\delta$, $\beta$, and some moments of $f_{\beta,t}$.
Already the paper of Carbery–Wright mentions an extension to plurisubharmonic functions, which might include the above example, but I am a novice and I thought it would be wise to ask whether this kind of statement (with explicit dependence) is known or essentially known, and/or whether it is hopeless (see below for the motivation).
Some reading has also turned up results for trigonometric polynomials (as in this survey) and for more general classes of functions. But I am most interested in making very precise statements about $f_{\beta,t}$. It may be the case that this machinery is the wrong way to answer such a narrow question.
The goal would be to study the bound as $\beta \uparrow \infty$ to recover some statment about the $\|{-}\|_\infty$ function.  Really I am mostly interested in the case where $\mu$ is a (non-isotropic) Gaussian measure, but the log concave case is also very interesting.
I was also playing with the idea of taking $d \asymp \log(n)$ in the Carbery–Wright bound directly, with the same goal in mind, but I will save that for another question.
